# Show that 3 and 1+2√-5 are relatively prime in Z[-√5]

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have tried to solve it by taking m,n∈Z, and applying mx+ny=1, but am getting rational values for m and n. I don't think it's the right way to solve it. Please help.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, right?

Comment: Yes. I am finding difficulty in writing the exact terms. Can you also help me out about how to write an exact mathematical expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that a common divisor of $3$ and $1+2\sqrt{-5}$ must be a unit.

Consider the norm $N(x+y\sqrt{-5})=x^2+5y^2$.

- $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$
- $\delta \mid \alpha \implies N(\delta) \mid N(\alpha)$
- $N(\alpha)=\pm 1 \iff \alpha$ is a unit
- $N(3)=9, N(1+2\sqrt{-5})=21$
- A common divisor of $3$ and $1+2\sqrt{-5}$ must have norm dividing $\gcd(9,21)$.

Comment: Since, gcd(9,21)=3, on solving N(x+y√-5)=3, I got x=√3, which is not the unit. Am I solving it right?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are integers!

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The next part of the question says if α=3, β=1+2√-5, show that αγ and βγ have no gcd in Z[√-5], where γ=7(1+2√-5). Approaching it as in the above question, we will always get 1(unit) which divide the norm of αγ and βγ. So, how can it have no gcd?

Comment: @Utkarsh, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Utkarsh did u manage to solve the second part?